# Rigid Body stopped working

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I don't know when, the Rigid Body just doesn't work in this project, only for the first 3 frames. Nothing helps.
Link to file: https://mega.nz/file/XHIgkB5K#_6b7vCFP8ilvlWQpefa6wscMyZPNSDvN4CJQcxrCkdM

Comment: did u try delete all bakes?

Comment: "did u try delete all bakes? " yes

Comment: i just can say: i downloaded your blend file, started animation...and it worked. Maybe download from your own link and try again? sometimes caches making weird things...

Comment: still no working, but when I copy this box to new project it works. This is madness

Comment: Yeah, blender 3.1 is a little buggy, these things happen from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Timeline > Playback*, choose *Play Every Frame* instead of *Sync to Audio*, even though I'm not sure why it makes it bug:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this fixed it for me